# want to use an XmlElement attribute on class?

Tags: asp.net, xml, serialization

I have the following class:

```
[XmlElement("email-address")]
    public class EmailAddress
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
    }
```

The XmlElement attribute is in valid here, but I do want this behavior - is this possible?  TO have the name of this class serialized in XML as `email-address` instead of `EmailAddress`?

Comment: So, what happens when you try this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [XmlTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0th2hysa%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to change how a class is serialized.